# Detect a button click in the browser_action form of a Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How can something so simple be so impossible?

All I want to do is click the browser_action button of my extension, open a form with a couple of settings, and then click the button on the form to kick off a process.

I cannot for the life of me get the button click in the background form to work.

I have tried to get the example at http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#H2-3 to work, but it doesn't.  Is there a difference between rules for browser_action and background? Is that why my event listener is not firing?

Can someone provide a working example, please?

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Convert",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Converts the current page",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "exticon.png",
        "default_popup": "background.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://*/*"],
        "js": ["contentscript_static.js"]
    }],
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

background.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Converter</title>
        <script src="background.js"/>
        <script>
        // Initialize the localStorage
        if (null == localStorage["htmlImport"])
           localStorage["htmlImport"] = false;

        // Called when the user clicks on the browser action icon.
        chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
            console.log('in listener');
                 // execute the content script
                 chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, 
                    {
                       file: "contentscript.js",
                       allFrames: true   // It doesn't work before 4.0.266.0.
                    });
              });

        // Listen to the requests from the content script
        chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
              function(request, sender, sendResponse)
              {
                 switch (request.name)
                 {
                    case "getPreferences":
                       sendResponse(
                          {
                             prefIgnoreLinks : localStorage["htmlImport"]
                          });
                       break;

                    case "PressShortcut":
                       sendResponse({});  // don't response.

                       // execute the content script
                       chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, 
                          {
                             file: "contentscript.js",
                             allFrames: true   // It doesn't work before 4.0.266.0.
                          });

                       break;

                    default:
                       sendResponse({});  // don't response.
                       break;
                 }
              });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body style='min-width:250px;'>
        Link depth: <input type='text' name='depth' value='3'/><br/>
        <input type='checkbox' name='changedomain'>Include external domains</input><br/>
        <button id='beginConvert'>Convert</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

background.js:

```
function awesome() {
  // Do something awesome!
  console.log('awesome')
}
function totallyAwesome() {
  // do something TOTALLY awesome!
  console.log('totallyAwesome')
}

function awesomeTask() {
  awesome();
  totallyAwesome();
}

function clickHandler(e) {
  setTimeout(awesomeTask, 1000);
}
// Add event listeners once the DOM has fully loaded by listening for the
// `DOMContentLoaded` event on the document, and adding your listeners to
// specific elements when it triggers.
//document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
//  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
//});

// Add event listeners once the DOM has fully loaded by listening for the
// DOMContentLoaded event on the document, and adding your listeners to
// specific elements when it triggers.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
//  console.log('event listener for button connected to beginConversion()');
    //document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', beginConversion);
    document.getElementById('beginConvert').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```

Comment: Sharing the code you have or a reduced example will greatly improve everyone's ability to help you. If you are following one of the examples on the page you linked to, which one are you using?

Comment: Added code samples, so that non-clairvoyant developers like Mike are also able to participate.  ;-)

Comment: Your manifest.json file references "contentscript_static.js" but is not included in your question.

Comment: It's not a good idea to have the background.html be the content for the popup. You should have a different html file for the popup.

Comment: You have embedded JS into your background.html file. I believe that this violates the new contentSecurityPolicy (in Manifest V2) which requires that JS is imported from external files. Embedding is no longer permitted.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

## Your Goal

- Click extension button
- Extension popup window opens with controls
- Execute script on current tab based on controls in extension popup

## Tips

- Think of the background page as the control hub. It takes incoming requests from various scripts in your Chrome extension, has elevated permissions to do things like cross-domain requests (if defined in the manifest), and more.
- You should use the [manifest version 2](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#manifest_version) since version 1 is deprecated.
- Manifest version 2 doesn't allow inline scripts so all scripts will need to be loaded as their own file.

---

## Example

### manifest.json

```js
{
    "name": "Stackoverflow Popup Example",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Run process on page activated by click in extension popup",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

### background.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch (request.directive) {
        case "popup-click":
            // execute the content script
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { // defaults to the current tab
                file: "contentscript.js", // script to inject into page and run in sandbox
                allFrames: true // This injects script into iframes in the page and doesn't work before 4.0.266.0.
            });
            sendResponse({}); // sending back empty response to sender
            break;
        default:
            // helps debug when request directive doesn't match
            alert("Unmatched request of '" + request + "' from script to background.js from " + sender);
        }
    }
);
```

### popup.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            body { min-width:250px; text-align: center; }
            #click-me { font-size: 20px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id='click-me'>Click Me!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

### popup.js

```js
function clickHandler(e) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({directive: "popup-click"}, function(response) {
        this.close(); // close the popup when the background finishes processing request
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById('click-me').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
})
```

### contentscript.js

```js
console.log("chrome extension party!");
```

---

## Running Example Screenshots

Clicking extension button with browser window opened to exampley.com

[image: Clicking extension button with browser window opened to exampley.com]

After clicking 'Click Me!' button in extension popup

[image: After clicking 'Click Me!' button in extension popup]

---

## Example files in zip

http://mikegrace.s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow/detect-button-click.zip

Comment: Thanks very much, Mike! Is there a difference between the source in your post and the contents of the .zip file? The reason I ask is because the .zip file seems to be corrupt or invalid.

Comment: There is no difference. Try again, it should work now. Also, don't forget to up vote and accept if it helped or solved your issue.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, this was VERY helpful! I accepted the answer.  Unfortunately, my reputation is two shy of being able to vote up an answer. I'll come back and do it when I'm less of a nobody. :-)

Comment: Glad to help. You should have enough rep now ; )

Comment: I have a question: in contentscript.js, how would I access an HTML element of popup.html?

Comment: It seems that this is not working anymore. I loaded the extension from .zip file in developer mode but its not working. Its not opening any tab. It's showing error

`Error during tabs.executeScript: Unknown error. sendRequest:22
chromeHidden.handleResponse`

Comment: @Rajkiran looks like you are correct. I will have to look into it and correct it. I'm guessing that changes in the extension API have broken this example on the latest versions of Chrome.

Comment: Hi, How do I use jQuery in this contentscript.js? I added jQuery to the `content_scripts` in the manifest, but I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

Comment: This closes the extension popup. Anyway to keep the popup open after user clicks the button?

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha remove  this.close(); in popup.js

Comment: @MikeGrace could you elaborate on how you would work w/ a more complex `contentscript.js` For example what if it ran a function you wrote? How would you return the results from that back to your `background.js` file? Would you use the `runtime.sendMessage` api with a different directive (i.e. "process-data") and have the results of the function call be part of the message?

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer does not work anymore and it took me a few hours to understand how to manage a work around. I hope this can get you going faster then me.

**First**, you the last method in [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) page (by the bottom of the page) and it is asynchronous, so remember to give it a callback. The code you need is smtg like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true}, getActiveTabCallback);
});
```

**Second**, you need to understand one thing that took me some time: if you are not using a background html page you won't be able to see any `console.log` in your main Chrome window. You need to go to the extension page (`chrome://extensions`) and click in your extensions `background page` link (yes, you don't have a background page but Chrome gives you a fake one). This type of extension (based on events) should have the manifest.json containing smtg like this:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
```

Regards!