# How to add borders around hovered divs preferably the feature should be activated after a button is clicked on the extension popup?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I would like to give the possibility to the user to hover on divs on a page and have a border appear temporarily around the hovered div

I'm actually adding style to all divs but that's not ideal

```
div:hover {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

It would be better to activate this mode when a user clicks on a button on the popup
like the example in the pictures below
[image: Hover on a div a show border]
[image: Hover on a div a show border]

Comment: No the button would activate the feature. Basically once activated the user can hover on any div on the page and it would add a border temporarily. Basically add a border on the div that is being hovered on (as seen in the pictures)

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561136/chrome-extension-to-change-dom-with-a-button-in-extension-popup) question which is about a similar situation.

For this issue, an example would look like this (adapted from linked question):

popup.js (linked in your popup):

```
document.getElementById('yourButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(activeTabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTabs[0].id, { action: 'injectCSS' });
    });
});
```

then you could include an `content.js` into every (or your preferred) site via your application's manifest file:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://airbnb.com/*"],    //or "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
      "js": ["js/content.js"]
    }
]
```

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
    if (request.action === 'injectCSS') {
        var css = document.createElement('style');
        css.innerHTML = 'div:hover { outline: 1px solid blue; }';
        document.head.appendChild(css);
    }
});
```

**Explanation:**
*popup.js* listens for the `onClick` event of the button ID `#yourButton` in your popup. If triggered, a message event is piped to the currently selected tab and handled by *content.js*, wich is linked into the site by your extension's manifest. This script then creates a new `<style>` element, pastes the CSS into it and appends it to the `<head>` section of the DOM.

I hope I could help!

Comment: Great thanks for your answer, no need to indicate Airbnb. It should work on any website where the user activate the extension

Comment: @AziCode Then you could just use `"matches": ["<all_urls>"]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you dynamically add a CSS class.

```js
element.classList.remove("nameClass")
element.classList.add("nameClass");
```

mdn classList : < https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList >

Example:

```js
 
let isEnabledHover = false;
let main = document.getElementById('myMain');

function myFunction() {
 
    if (isEnabledHover) {
        isEnabledHover = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < main.children.length; i++) {
          main.children[i].classList.remove("useRequireBorder");
      } 
    } else {
        isEnabledHover = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < main.children.length; i++) {
            main.children[i].classList.add("useRequireBorder");
        }
    }
    
 
}
```

```css
.useRequireBorder:hover{
      outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="myMain">
  <div>
    <button onClick="myFunction()">enabled hover element</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Hello World</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>Hello World</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```