# Change of variables via popup

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I am doing a Chrome extension and I have a problem. It is supposed to click button on the page.

I want to use a variable that I can change via the popup because I don't want to go to the script all the time and change the variable. How do I do that?

I want to change the variable `sku` via popup.

Manifest:

```json
{
      "name": "Clicker",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "version": "0.0.1",
         "browser_action": {
         "default_popup": "popup.html",
         "default_title": "popup",
         "default_icon": "icon.png"
             },
      "description": "Clicker",
        "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://www.zalando.pl/*"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
        "permissions": [
        "tabs", "storage" ,"activeTab", "http://*/*", "https://*/*",    
        "<all_urls>",
            "*://*/*",
            "tabs",
            "storage", 
            "webRequest",
            "webRequestBlocking",
        "webNavigation",
        "alarms",
        "cookies"
      ]
}
```

`popup.html`:

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <h1>Esensial Scripts</h1>
    <input type="text" id="sku" placeholder="Enter Sku Here"/>
    <input type="submit" id="Save" value="Save"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

`content.js`:

```js
var spicker = "size-picker-";
var sku = "NI112O0J9-A110075000";

//example var sku = "XXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX";
                 
const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}
    
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    sleep(1).then(() => {
        document.getElementById(spicker + sku).click();
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/). You should call `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` in popup.html (or to be more concise popup.js loaded by popup.html) when the button is clicked and listen to the message with `chrome.runtime.onMessage` in content.js.

There are other methods that you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561136/chrome-extension-to-change-dom-with-a-button-in-extension-popup).